# Calendar Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, calendar

So I have this spreadsheet full with names and comments. I want that all the info to be changed when I change the date from the calendar. For today I have 5 people and 5 comments but when I change the date on tomorrow this comments and people remain, I want them to be erased (so new people and new comments to be added) and the ones from today to remain saved so I can go back. Is this possible? Does anyone understands or I'm just stupid on explaining? I can make a print screen if it helps. Please help!

Comment: Please share a screenshot :)